# Validate children before creating parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

How can I create a parent model only if its children models fit some validations alltogether like the sum of their attributes equal come value, etc?

I have an parent model as:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, allow_destroy: true

end
```

And the child model as:

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :foo

end
```

Is there a right way of doing it? Where should I validate the children models? Also how could I test it with rspec? Like this?

```
before do
  @foo = create(:foo)
  @bar = create(:bar, value: 30, foo_id: @foo.id)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails offers [validates_associated](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated), which will ensure the associated records are valid. If the associated records are invalid, the parent record will not be saved.

In `Foo`:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, allow_destroy: true

  validates_associated :bars
end
```

In `Bar`:

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with BarValidator
end
```

In `BarValidator`, which is [a custom validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators):

```
class BarValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors.add :some_error, 'Some message' unless condition_met?
  end
end
```

You've stated:

> only if its children models fit some validations alltogether like the sum of their attributes equal come value, etc?

which is somewhat ambiguous. If you truly *do* need to calculate the sum of children then you can add a validator to the parent which maps through the children and appends an error on failure to meet conditional:

In `Foo`, (or preferably, a validator):

```
validate :children_condition

def children_condition
  errors[:base] << "Some message" if bars.map(&:attribute).sum != expected_minimum_value
end
```

Important notes from the documentation on validates_associated:

> WARNING: This validation must not be used on both ends of an association. Doing so will lead to a circular dependency and cause infinite recursion.

> NOTE: This validation will not fail if the association hasn't been assigned. If you want to ensure that the association is both present and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use validates_presence_of.

As for:

> Also how could I test it with rspec?

I would create a test suite of valid parent, valid child && valid parent, invalid child, etc and expect the `Model.count` to have increased by the expected amount (which would be zero in the latter example).

Comment: When testing validations you don't really need to create records. You can just call `#valid?` on the model and then set expectations [on the errors object](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).You can test actually creating the records indirectly through a feature or request spec.